# Design implications of Balloon Tooltip vs Rectangular Tooltip

Tags: gui-design, design, affordance, tooltips

I'm using a tooltip for a validation message and trying to weigh different design options.

I'm curious because in this walkthrough on using [`MaskedTextBox.ValidatingType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.validatingtype), they go out of their way to suggest using [`ToolTip.IsBalloon = True`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.isballoon), even though the distinction would otherwise be immaterial to the example.

*Do **Rectangular vs Balloon** Tooltips afford different kinds of usages?*

[image: ToolTip Options]

My guess would be that rectangular tooltips are more often used for supplemental information whereas balloons with an arrow indicate information directly related to a field or value.

Anybody have any input on the differences/usages?

Answer (score 2):

To me, the advantage of the balloon tooltip is that the small triangle points directly to the element that it relates to, which reduces ambiguity in a crowded user interface

You can argue the user knows where his mouse/finger is pointing, but one scenario it's actually useful for is disseminating screenshots that don't show the mouse pointer or supply amputated fingers as context